# Finding the indicated probability using tables of the Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have 3 questions that I'm trying to figure out. Lesson was on a day I was absent so I have no notes to go based off of. See below

Find the indicated probability using the standard normal distribution.

1. $P(Z < 3.21)$
2. $P(Z > 2.35)$
3. $P(1.52 < Z < 3.31)$

Comment: Do you have access to Excel?

Comment: One way to do that, is to consult a Cumulative Standard Normal Table. You can find those on the internet or in your stats book. While these values can also be found through other devices (excel, Ti 84, etc), it is imperative to be able to read the values from a table as well, as it is important for the learning process. So do you have such a table? On a side note....You could copy notes from a fellow student?

Comment: And this link might also be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85G_PLBTX00

Comment: I do have a chart, I was trying to post it but since I'm new it says I can't post photos. So would I just go looking against the chart, for example the 3.21 and find the number that matches?

Comment: I do have access to excel

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. I did get notes from the person who sits next to me but I can't make any sense of it

Comment: In this case the "standard normal distribrution" is so widely known that supplying a picture of your table is not necessary.  Instead I recommend that you look at the table and try to relate its entries to your problems, adding your observations/attempts at solution to the problem.  That will give you the benefit of learning how the table works.

Answer (score 1):

This is for one style of the standard normal table. Adjust as necessary
for the one you have.
For $P(Z < 3.21)$ look in the left margin of the table
to find 3.2, then at the top margin to find .01.
Where the row and column intersect you will find 0.9993
if your table is a true CDF table.

Otherwise you might
find .4993 for $P(0 < Z < 3.21)$ and you need to add
0.5 because $P(Z < 0) = 0.5000.$ For example, [the NIST normal table](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3671.htm)
requires adding 0.5 to  0.49934, and gives five-place accuracy.

In R statistical software, `> pnorm(3.21)` returns 0.9993363.
In Minitab,

```
MTB > cdf 3.21;
SUBC> norm 0 1.
Normal with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1
   x  P( X ≤ x )
3.21    0.999336
```

And many other sofware packages have similar capabilities.

Notice that $P (Z > 2.35) = 1 - P(Z \le 2.35)$ and use the
same method to find $P(Z \le 2.35).$

Notice that $P (1.25 < Z < 3.31) = P(Z < 3.31) - P(Z < 1.25).$ [Slightly
different from your problem.]
In R you could use

```
> pnorm(3.31) - pnorm(1.25)
[1] 0.1051833
```

It is always a good idea to make sketches when you have to add or
subtract probabilities. In the last problem 0.1052 is the approximate
area under the standard normal density curve between the vertical lines.

[image]